# How to check if user have rights to view the document

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a script that checks if the user have rights to view a document, i am doing this with two database table. in order to list all the document title that he have rights.

I have the results but when i assign a document to Table-2 is not showing probably because is outside of the cycle while.

If i insert it inside the cycle while i get the same title each time i add a new record to Table-2 || (ex. Title 1 on Table-1 will be shown 4 times)

Table-1

```
id | document  |
1  | Title 1   |
2  | Title 2   |
3  | Title 3   |
4  | Title 4   |
```

Table-2

```
id | userid  | docid  |
1  | 1       |   2    |
2  | 1       |   3    |
3  | 2       |   2    |
4  | 1       |   4    |
```

Script

```
        $query = "SELECT * FROM docdistributed order by id DESC";
        $result = mysql_query($query);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {

        $id_distributed = $row["id"];
        $userdistributed = 1;

        $albums_query = "SELECT * FROM docacknowledge order by id DESC";
        $albums_result = mysql_query($albums_query);

        while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($albums_result))
        {
        $id_acknowledge = $row1["docid"];
        $useracknowledge  = $row1["userid"];


        if ($id_distributed == $id_acknowledge && $userdistributed == $useracknowledge){

        $node = 0;

        } else {
        $node = 1;

        }



        }

if($node==0){
echo'<tr style="background-color:#;">';
echo'<td>'.$row["id"].'</td>';
echo'<td>'.$row["document"].'</td>';
echo'<td>';
echo'<div class="btn-group">';
echo'<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Action</button>';
echo'<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">';
echo'<span class="caret"></span>';
echo'<span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>';
echo'</button>';
echo'<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">';
echo'<li><a href="#">Open</a></li>';
echo'<li><a href="#">Download</a></li>';
echo'</ul>';
echo'</div>';
echo'</td>';
echo'</tr>';
}


if($node==1){
echo'<tr style="background-color:#FFFFDF;">';
echo'<td>'.$row["id"].'</td>';
echo'<td>'.$row["document"].'</td>';
echo'<td>';
echo'<div class="btn-group">';
echo'<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Action</button>';
echo'<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">';
echo'<span class="caret"></span>';
echo'<span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>';
echo'</button>';
echo'<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">';
echo'<form id="ack" action="ack_bulletin.php" method="post"><input type="text"  name="docid" value="'.$row["id"].'"><input type="text" name="userid" value="'.$userdistributed.'"><li onclick="ack.submit();"><a href="#">Acknowledge</a></li></form>';
echo'</ul>';
echo'</div>';
echo'</td>';
echo'</tr>';
}
        }

?>
```

Comment: You described a problem in your question title, and yet another completely different problem in your question text. For which one you want help?

Comment: (and please, do not use `mysql_` functions, they are *deprecated*, switch it to `PDO`)

Comment: Hi @AlanMachado i need help for my question text. thanks

Comment: Yes. You have a `while` inside another `while`, where the second one assigns the same values to your local variables each time the first one iterates.

Answer (score 0):

You should take advantage of a MySQL `LEFT JOIN` on the two database tables so you don't need to do these nested loops and only get the required data in 1 `SELECT`. Try using this query:

```
    SELECT *
      FROM docdistributed dd
 LEFT JOIN docacknowledge da ON dd.id = da.docid
  ORDER BY dd.id DESC
```

This effectively replaces the need for using PHP-based logic like this:

```
if ($id_distributed == $id_acknowledge && $userdistributed == $useracknowledge) {
```

which in turn prevents dilemmas like the one described whereby you are at the mercy of which bits of relational data are available at certain junctures of the script.